# A temporary file could not opened to write the process output: fopen (C:\Windows\Temp\sf_proc_00.out.lock)

Tags: laravel, symfony, browsershot

Using Browsershot, I am getting this error:

```
A temporary file could not opened to write the process output: fopen (C:\Windows\Temp\sf_proc_00.out.lock)
```

My user is an MSA account on a Windows Server and he is not an admin, so he doesn't have write permissions to `C:\Windows\Temp`.

But also, changing the temp folder path in Browsershot does not help. when I use `setCustomTempPath(storage_path('temp'))`, it still gives the above error.

I do see that it tries to write the temp file to the new path that has the right permissions, but from some reason it also tries to do something in `C:\Windows\Temp`, even though the temp file is written to the new location (Something to do with Windows Pipes).

So I am not sure what it tries to do there with the pipes.

Can I change it? Or fix it in another way?

Comment: did you figure this out? I have same issue